# Strange __block storage variable crash

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem in my code which I have distilled down to the following (silly) example

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

__block NSString *a = @"-1";

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id whoCares, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", a, idx];
    NSLog(@"%@", a);
}];

NSLog(@"%@", a);
```

This code works, but if I comment out the first NSLog (within the block) the code crashes. But, if I change the format string to the following

```
a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idx];
```

then the code runs fine without the NSLog within the block.

What is going on here? I hope I am just misunderstanding something.

Comment: Is that ALL of the code?

Comment: Also what is the specific crash you're seeing.

Comment: This is just a made up example of what I am really doing. I have an  array that I enumerate with a block, and I reassign a variable with a value derived from itself. It was a bad access error on the last NSLog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringWithFormat:` gives you an autoreleased object, which you're not retaining.  By the time the block exits and you call `NSLog`, `a` might have already been deallocated.

One solution might be to use a mutable string and append to it each time instead of reassigning.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

NSMutableString *a = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"-1"];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id whoCares, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [a appendFormat:@" %d", idx];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", a);
```

Comment: I now feel silly for not thinking of blocks as having their own scope, thanks. I did move the solution to use a mutable data structure, which worked better anyway. I was still curious what was going on though, the fact that the first NSLog prevented the crash was confusing me but it makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: Almost right; you don't need `__block` if you are using an NSMutableString.  That the NSLog() prevented the crash was entirely coincidental and, no, it doesn't make sense because the behavior is undefined in that case. :)

Comment: @bbum Quite right, edited out the __block, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @bbum That it is undefined is why it makes sense to me :-) Thanks for the help everyone.